# Remove square brackets from Select-Object result

Tags: powershell

So I have this Powershell-script that is supposed to get the status of all SQL Agent Jobs in my cluster.
The problem is that one of the objects value is withing square brackets, here is the code:

```
$output = ForEach ($instance in $instances)
{
    $instanceName = $instance.InstanceName
    Get-SqlAgentJob -ServerInstance "$env:computername\$instanceName" |
        Where-Object {$_.IsEnabled -eq "True" -and $_.LastRunDate -gt [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-2)} |
            Select-Object Name,Description,Parent,LastRunOutcome,LastRunDate,LastRunDuration,HasSchedule,@{
                name='JobSchedules'
                expression={$_.JobSchedules -join ','}
                }
}
```

This is the $output:

```
Name            : TestJob
Description     : No description available.
Parent          : [SERVER\INSTANCE]
LastRunOutcome  : Succeeded
LastRunDate     : 2020-06-01 05:30:00
LastRunDuration : 00:03:44
HasSchedule     : True
JobSchedules    : Daily
```

As you can see, the "Parent" object is within square brackets [], how do I delete them in the end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell has a feature called Calculated properties you can use to solve this.

It uses this syntax where `Property1` and `Property2` are normal properties:

```
Select-Object Property1,Property2, @{Name=‘NewColumn‘;Expression={<#code to calculate#>}}
```

For instance, if you wanted to show the file size of each item in a directory in Megabytes, you could just add this column to your `Select-Object` command for `Get-ChildItem`.

```
dir | Select-Object Name,Length,@{Name='SizeMB';Exp={$_.Length/1mb -as [int]}}

Name                                                       Length SizeMB
----                                                       ------ ------
My Neighbor Totoro OST - 03 A Haunted House.mp4           4530480      4
myCoolBmp.bmp                                                1243      0
Ponyo Theme Song (with lyrics)-vUCnXCyUm7w.mp4            7884658      8
ResultUI.png                                                42887      0
shutUpandTakeMyMoney.png                                   575992      1
SomeNotes.txt                                                  14      0
SONIC • Chill Out Music Compilation (Part 1).mkv        168230106    160
The Village in May (My Neighbor Totoro)-5QXF2GeniSY.mp4   2686660      3
twimage.png                                                167827      0
Video Game Music for Studying 19-P-BqmegCUpA.webm       359146270    343
```

So, to put it in practice for you, in the `Select-Object` statement simply remove `Parent` and replace it with

```
@{Name=‘Parent‘;Expression={$_.Parent.Replace('[','').Replace(']','')}}
```

Comment: A little shorter would be something like this:  `'[SERVER\INSTANCE]' -replace '[][]'`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however Parent now returns null.
Isn't "at" for an array?

@Olaf
Then I have it to loop again?

Comment: @Salve No. You can simply use a calculated property like FoxDeploy recommends but you could change the actual expression to be `{ $_.Parent -replace '[][]' }`

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick, here is the working code:

`Select-Object Name,Description,@{Name=‘Parent‘;Expression={$_.Parent -Replace '[][]'}},LastRunOutcome,LastRunDate,LastRunDuration,OwnerLoginName,HasSchedule,@{Name='JobSchedules';Expression={$_.JobSchedules -join ','}}`